# Javafx - populating table with xml file

Tags: javafx

I am fairly new to javafx and have been following a tutorial (http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/) where all my code has come from.

I am having an issue with populating a table with an xml file which I believe is because I want to switch scene first and then display the table on this new scene. In the guide they do it on just the first scene that loads, which if I do I can get to work fine, but when I want the table data to be viewable on a different scene, it doesn't seem to work. All I did was change where some of the code was located within the class to try to reflect this as I didn't want it on my first scene but now it won't display.

**LibraryApp**

```
package libraryapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import libraryapp.model.Book;
import libraryapp.model.BookListWrapper;
import libraryapp.view.HomeOverviewController;
import libraryapp.view.RootLayoutController;

public class LibraryApp extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;

/**
 * The data as an observable list of Books.
 */
private ObservableList<Book> bookData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public LibraryApp() {
    // Add some sample data
    bookData.add(new Book("Hans", "Muster"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Ruth", "Mueller"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Heinz", "Kurz"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Cornelia", "Meier"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Werner", "Meyer"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Lydia", "Kunz"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Anna", "Best"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Stefan", "Meier"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Martin", "Mueller"));
}

/**
 * Returns the data as an observable list of Books. 
 * @return
 */
public ObservableList<Book> getBookData() {
    return bookData;
}



@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("LibraryApp");

    initRootLayout();
    showHomeOverview();

 }


/**
* Initializes the root layout and tries to load the last opened
* person file.
*/
public void initRootLayout() {
try {
    // Load root layout from fxml file.
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
           loader.setLocation(LibraryApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
    rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

    // Show the scene containing the root layout.
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    // Give the controller access to the main app.
    RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setLibraryApp(this);

    primaryStage.show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Try to load last opened person file.
File file = getBookFilePath();
if (file != null) {
    loadBookDataFromFile(file);
}
}





/**
 * Shows the book overview inside the root layout.
 */
public void showHomeOverview() {
    try {
        // Load home overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
          loader.setLocation(LibraryApp.class.getResource("view/HomeOverview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane homeOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();



        // Set home overview into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(homeOverview);

    // Give the controller access to the main app.
    HomeOverviewController controller = loader.getController();



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the main stage.
 * @return
 */
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

/**
 * Returns the book file preference, i.e. the file that was last opened.
* The preference is read from the OS specific registry. If no such
* preference can be found, null is returned.
* 
* @return
*/
public File getBookFilePath() {
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(LibraryApp.class);
String filePath = prefs.get("filePath", null);
if (filePath != null) {
    return new File(filePath);
} else {
    return null;
}
}

/**
* Sets the file path of the currently loaded file. The path is persisted in
* the OS specific registry.
* 
* @param file the file or null to remove the path
*/
public void setBookFilePath(File file) {
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(LibraryApp.class);
if (file != null) {
    prefs.put("filePath", file.getPath());

    // Update the stage title.
    primaryStage.setTitle("LibraryApp - " + file.getName());
} else {
    prefs.remove("filePath");

    // Update the stage title.
    primaryStage.setTitle("LibraryApp");
}
}

/**
* Loads book data from the specified file. The current book data will
* be replaced.
* 
* @param file
*/
public void loadBookDataFromFile(File file) {
try {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
            .newInstance(BookListWrapper.class);
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

    // Reading XML from the file and unmarshalling.
    BookListWrapper wrapper = (BookListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);

    bookData.clear();
    bookData.addAll(wrapper.getBooks());

    // Save the file path to the registry.
    setBookFilePath(file);

} catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("Error");
    alert.setHeaderText("Could not load data");
    alert.setContentText("Could not load data from file:\n" +       file.getPath());

    alert.showAndWait();
}
}

/**
 * Saves the current book data to the specified file.
* 
* @param file
*/
public void saveBookDataToFile(File file) {
try {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
            .newInstance(BookListWrapper.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    // Wrapping our book data.
    BookListWrapper wrapper = new BookListWrapper();
    wrapper.setBooks(bookData);

    // Marshalling and saving XML to the file.
    m.marshal(wrapper, file);

    // Save the file path to the registry.
    setBookFilePath(file);
} catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("Error");
    alert.setHeaderText("Could not save data");
    alert.setContentText("Could not save data to file:\n" + file.getPath());

    alert.showAndWait();
}
}



}
```

**HomeOverViewController**

```
package libraryapp.view;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import libraryapp.view.BrowseController;


public class HomeOverviewController implements Initializable {


@FXML
private AnchorPane homePane;



@FXML
private void goToBrowse(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    AnchorPane pane =   FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Browse.fxml"));
    homePane.getChildren().setAll(pane);

}

@FXML
private void goToManageAccount(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    AnchorPane pane =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ManageAccount.fxml"));
    homePane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
}

@FXML
public void logout(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
    homePane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

}
```

**BrowseController**

```
package libraryapp.view;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import libraryapp.LibraryApp;
import libraryapp.model.Book;

public class BrowseController {
@FXML
private TableView<Book> bookTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Book, String> titleColumn;

@FXML
private Label titleLabel;
@FXML
private Label authorLabel;
@FXML
private Label isbnLabel;
@FXML
private Label quantityLabel;

@FXML
private AnchorPane browsePane;


// Reference to the main application.
private LibraryApp libraryApp;

/**
 * The constructor.
 * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
 */
public BrowseController() {
}

/**
 * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
 * after the fxml file has been loaded.
 */
@FXML
private void initialize() {
// Initialize the book table
titleColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        cellData -> cellData.getValue().titleProperty());

// Clear person details.
showBookDetails(null);

// Listen for selection changes and show the person details when changed.
bookTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
        (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showBookDetails(newValue));
}



 /**
 * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
 * 
 * @param libraryApp
 */
public void setLibraryApp(LibraryApp libraryApp) {
    this.libraryApp = libraryApp;

    // Add observable list data to the table
    bookTable.setItems(libraryApp.getBookData());
}




private void showBookDetails(Book book) {
if (book != null) {
    // Fill the labels with info from the book object.
    titleLabel.setText(book.getTitle());
    authorLabel.setText(book.getAuthor());
    isbnLabel.setText(book.getIsbn());
    quantityLabel.setText(Integer.toString(book.getQuantity()));


} else {
    // Book is null, remove all the text.
    titleLabel.setText("");
    authorLabel.setText("");
    isbnLabel.setText("");
    quantityLabel.setText("");

}


}


/**
 * Called when the user clicks on the borrow button.
*/
@FXML
private void handleDeleteBook() {
int selectedIndex = bookTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
    bookTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
} else {
    // Nothing selected.
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
    alert.initOwner(libraryApp.getPrimaryStage());
    alert.setTitle("No Selection");
    alert.setHeaderText("No book Selected");
    alert.setContentText("Please select a book.");

    alert.showAndWait();
  }
}


@FXML
public void logout(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        File bookFile = libraryApp.getBookFilePath();
        libraryApp.saveBookDataToFile(bookFile);


    AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
    browsePane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
}

}
```

The idea is that I want to press a button which calls `goToBrowse` which will load the Browse scene and then populate the table there with the data from the xml file. It goes to browse scene fine but does not populate the table.

Please excuse any messy code and any bad naming conventions as I am pretty new to this javafx stuff and have been trying to follow the tutorial that was mentioned before and tweak it to what I thought would be correct.

I believe it is the `setLibraryApp` that I want to be calling in the `BrowseController`, but what I have tried doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand your code. In `BrowseController` your `setLibraryApp` method displays the data in the table, but I don't see anywhere where you call that method. Also, in your `showHomeOverview` method you have the comment "Give the controller access to the main app.", but then you don't actually do that.

Comment: There was a line of code at the end of showHomeOverview underneath that comment which was controller.setLibraryApp(this); similar to what they had in the tutorial but since I wasn't displaying the data in that scene I removed it from there and why I try to add it there, it states no such method exists.

I will admit I have also confused myself with trying to follow this tutorial but tweaking it to fit what I need which is getting that setLibaryApp method to be called when I load the Browse scene but whatever I try doesn't seem to work, so i'm sure i am not not understanding something with it

Comment: If you want `HomeController` to provide the `LibraryApp` to `BrowseController`, `HomeController` will need access to it first. Sounds like the tutorial you are following has shown you how to do that: you just need to do it (twice) the same way.

Comment: I believe now I have given both `HomeController` and `BrowseController` access to `LibraryApp` but i'm still not too sure how I get the table to populate with the data once I navigate to the Browse scene. I'm sure i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: `bookTable.setItems(libraryApp.getBookData());`

Comment: Working, forgot to change the code on the button that takes me to the browse scene.

Is there a way I can mark this as answered? New to stackoverflow, so not sure.

Anyways, thank you for bearing with me and helping!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer if I have time later...